# Cocos2D collision detection of CCSprites on different CCNodes with different position and rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a hierarchy like this:

Scene
 - gameWorld (CCLayer Z:0)
    - player (CCSprite Z:1)
 - spriteWorld (CCNode Z:0)
    - bgSprite (CCSprite Z:0)
       - enemy (CCSprite Z:0)

The spriteWorld gets rotated and the bgSprite gets moved around so any CCSprites placed on bgSprite has a rotated and moved coordinate system compared to the gameWorld coordinate system.

I need to detected collisions between CCSprites placed both on the gameWorld and bgSprite. Now I have seen this post here:

[Cocos2D CCNode position in absolute screen coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766522/cocos2d-ccnode-position-in-absolute-screen-coordinates)

which can give me each sprites position relative to the screen, but how do I then calculate or get the bounding box for these sprites? Those bounding boxes are rotate both via the spriteWorld rotation but each sprite also rotates on the bgSprite.

Sounds like a lot of crazy math to me and I am a fool at math, so I really really need help here.

Thank you
Særen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, cocos2D has no direct support for collision detection, so you would need to do all your calculations on your own.

Anyway, you can use a framework like [chipmunk-physics](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=chipmunk%20physics&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDQQFjAC&url=http://chipmunk-physics.net/&ei=3aG3Tui4BY298gOY5LymBQ&usg=AFQjCNG0ZDDuDLDJgU2KsKAFICwlQ3b4XA) or [Box2D](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=box2d&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://box2d.org/&ei=yqG3TtT9LcPRhAfvmeylBA&usg=AFQjCNGzFEkO1SyN04eBDL7OCZ10fw6iWA) to do that for you. The basic idea is that you associate a body/shape to your sprite and then setup a collision callback that will be fired when the collision is detected, without worrying about the math...

Have a look at this article about [using Box2D just for collision detection](http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone).