# Trouble with Translate CCNode using convertToWorldSpaceAR

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm a bit confused by the behaviour of my Cocos2d instance, and I need some help.  I borrowed this code from [Cocos2D CCNode position in absolute screen coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766522/cocos2d-ccnode-position-in-absolute-screen-coordinates).  Pretty simple: two objects, one a child of the other.

Running the below code snippet, I am getting worldCoord = (50, 200).  My expectation would be that the translation would result in worldCoord = (100, 150).  When I step through the code, tx = 100, and ty = 150 in the CGAffineTransform.  Why?

```
CCNode * myNode = [[CCNode alloc] init];
[myNode setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
myNode.position = CGPointMake(150.0f, 100.0f);

CCNode * mySprite = [[CCNode alloc] init]; // CCSprite is a descendant of CCNode
[mySprite setAnchorPoint:CGPointZero];
[myNode addChild: mySprite];
mySprite.position = CGPointMake(-50.0f, 50.0f);

// we now have a node with a sprite in in. On this sprite (well, maybe
// it you should attack the node to a scene) you can call convertToWorldSpace:
CGPoint worldCoord = [mySprite convertToWorldSpaceAR: mySprite.position];
```

Comment: The "AR" variants of the convert functions are relative to the anchorPoint. Try the non-AR variant, I bet this will give you the expected result.

Comment: no dice.  However, if I call [myNode convertToWorldSpace: mySprite.position] I get the expected worldCoord = (100, 150).  Why would that context change make a difference?

Comment: Just to add to that, I played with the anchors, but got the same result no matter the anchorpt, and regardless of the variant of the convertToWorldSpace message.

Comment: ok, I tried using CGAffineTransform t = [self nodeToWorldTransform], and t.tx and t.ty gives the correct translations to the WorldCoordinates, so I'm going to use that.  However, if there is an explanation to the above, that would be good.  I'm sure it's something that I am missing that might help me understand Cocos2d better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that mySprite is a child of myNode and thus offset by the myNode position:

```
myNode.position = CGPointMake(150.0f, 100.0f);
mySprite.position = CGPointMake(-50.0f, 50.0f);
```

Then you are correct to assume that mySprite's world pos should be:

```
X: (150 + -50) = 100
Y: (100 +  50) = 150
```

To get the sprite's world position use the non-AR variant of `convertToWorldSpace`:

```
CGPoint worldCoord = [myNode convertToWorldSpace: mySprite.position];
```

Note that you need to convert using the parent node, as it defines the coordinate space for its children. In other words a child node's origin (0,0) is equivalent to the position of its parent.

This variant of the method will also not be affected by changes in the sprite's anchorPoint. Only the 'AR' variant's results will change when you change the sprite anchor point.

The 'AR' variant simply adds the node's `anchorPoint` to the position before converting it. Assuming your sprite's `contentSize` is 100x100 and the `anchorPoint` is at the default 0.5,0.5 then 50,50 is added to `mySprite.position` before being converted to world space. In other words it adds the offset between the sprite texture's lower left corner to the sprite's position to the converted position.

Comment: Actually, [mySprite convertToWorldSpace: mySprite.position] gives me the incorrect result.  however, [myNode convertToWorldSpace mysprite.position] gives me the correct answer.

Comment: Just to add to this, when I stepped through the code, the tx was the y coord from the parent node, and the ty was the x coord from the parent node, which is not correct.  I'm inclined to say this is a bug in my cocos lib, but I can't believe I'd be the only one to see that.  But, code examples on simple transforms have not worked correctly for me (related to clipping).

Comment: Ah yes of course, you always have to convert from the parent's node space, in this case myNode. The thing is that child nodes use their parent's node space in terms of coordinates, ie their origin point (0,0) is the parent's position.

Comment: Ok!  This is good to know.  The question I referenced was incorrect then.  hopefully without belabouring this then, do you have an explanation for the result when I tried to convert the point relative to itself?  Was it just coincidence that the axes ended up looking switched?

Comment: maybe, or maybe it's just what the calculation does in that case